# ckeditor: how to load contents in submenu?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, ckeditor, submenu

I need a drop down list within a drop down list in the plugin . for this I have made a plugin that is showing a drop down list but **contents of inner drop down are not appearing**.
here is how i am doing this:

```
init : function( editor )
    {
                items = {};
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < markup.length ; i++ )
        {
            items[ parts[ 0 ] ] =
                {
                    label : parts[ 0 ],
                    group : 'microdata',
                    icon: this.path + 'icon1.png' ,
                    order : i,
                    getItems: function()
                        {
                            var selection = editor.getSelection();
                            return {
                                name: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
                                friend: CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF
                            };
                        }
        }
        editor.addMenuGroup( 'microdata' );
        editor.addMenuItems( items,friend:
                {
                  label: 'friend',
                  group: 'microdata',
                  //command: 'friendCmd',
                  order: 10
                }
                );
        editor.ui.add( 'Microdata', CKEDITOR.UI_MENUBUTTON,
        {
            label: 'Microdata',
            command: 'Microdata',
            modes : { wysiwyg:1 },
            className : 'cke_button_microdata',
            icon: this.path + 'icon1.png' ,
                    onMenu : function()
                {
                    var activeItems = {};

                    for ( var prop in items )
                    {
                        if ( items.hasOwnProperty( prop ) )
                            activeItems[ prop ] = CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON;
                    }
                    return  activeItems;
                }
        } );
```